# sass parent of parent specificity

Tags: sass, bem

I write CSS in BEM style and have this code:

```
.nav {
    &__list {
      &__item {
      }    
    }
  &__link {
    &--active { 
    }
  }
}
```

How do I get `.nav .nav__link--active` and `.nav__link.nav__link--active` from code above? How can I enhance the specificity by this method?

Comment: I'm not sure why you using cascade for `.nav .nav__link--active` and combining `.nav__link` with `.nav__link--active`. If you drop `.nav` and and `.nav__link` all be fine, the specificity will be 1, and you should just sort your selectors in the right order. Don't overextend ;-)

Answer (score 4):

There is no magic method for this.  Store the desired selector as a variable and nest like normal.

```
.nav {
  $sel: &;
    &__list {
      &__item {
        color: red;
        #{$sel} & {
          border: 1px solid;
        }
      }    
    }
  &__link {
    &--active {
      color: blue;
      #{$sel} & {
        border: 1px dashed;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice tip for SASS users! ;-) But please don't use `block__elem__elem`. This kind of selectors is Anti-pattern.