# How to modify multiple elements of a block with BEM CSS

Tags: css, block, element, modifier, bem

Let us say I have the following setup,

```
.block
  .block__header
  .block__content
  .block__footer
```

Now I want to show an active state of this block. Let us say the block itself gets a green background and element 2 and 3 should get bold text. As I understand the philosophy of BEM, one should not use child selectors in order to keep the specificity as low as possible.

So is this really the way to do it?

```
.block.block--active
  .block__header
  .block__content.block__content--active
  .block__footer.block__footer--active
```

Update: and how would I write that solution in SASS (very new to it)? This my setup so far... if I can use nested selectors, what is best practice here?

```
.block {
  &--active {

  }
  &__header {

  }
  &__content {
    // active modifier of content
    &--active {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    // would be the same as
    .block--active & {
      font-weight: bold;        
    }
    // but can i reference the active block somehow else in sass? 
    // & is a parent selector but i would need the parent of the parent here...
  }
  &__footer {
    &--active {

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure these 3 elements are different? If you give some more concrete example answer will be more helpful.

Comment: yes i am sure :) edited the code just to make clear....

Comment: i found something very useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28499176/1358484

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The philosophy of BEM is about to keep blocks context free. The low specificity is just a good practice, not a golden rule. I give three valid solutions below.

If you're sure the block cannot be recursively included in itself, a simple cascade can be used:

```
.block--active {
    background-color: green;
}
.block--active .block__element-2,
.block--active .block__element-3 {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

If the elements are directly located in the block, the children selector is valid:

```
.block--active {
    background-color: green;
}
.block--active > .block__element-2,
.block--active > .block__element-3 {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Or the flat solution (but not DRY):

```
.block--active {
    background-color: green;
}
.block__element-2--active,
.block__element-3--active {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

---

With SCSS, there are several ways to write the first solution. Here is the one I use:

```
.block {
    &--active {
        background-color: green;
    }
    &--active &__element-2,
    &--active &__element-3 {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
}
```

See [another solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26303557/sass-with-bem-inherit-selector/26303816#26303799).